# Rva to raw file offset in PE

Tags: windows, pe, address

What is really correct translation algorithm to get an offset in portable executable file from relative virtual address of some byte in the image?

I see next cases:

1. RVA points into the header part of image
2. RVA points into a section part presented in file
3. RVA points into a section part not presented in file (some loadtime initialized data)
4. RVA points out of image

For the first case it's like RVA is equal to offset in a file. (If all parts of file are mapped to the image. I'm not sure about DOS header.)

Further, mapped section can be biger than section in a file so some RVAs jast have no offset like RVA that points out of image.

And last things that I does not undestand at all. Are the values of fildes SizeOfImage, VirtualSize, VirtualAddress, PointerToRawData, SizeOfRawData already take into consideration file alignment and section alignment?

I saw some realizations of RvaToRaw full of black magic that made a correction for alignments, but without any explanation.

If no more alignment is needed so for case 2 it's

```
raw = rva - rvaOfSection + SectionRaw
```

Comment: @DarthGizka Did you read the thread you linked? I don't ask about some disasm tools and even about Virtual Adress. The scope of my question are only RVA and "raw".

Comment: The link leads to an answer containing a simple overview and a simple explanation, which should drive home the importance of the section table for converting between RVA and file offset. The **exact** details can get tricky, like the question when exactly Windows starts ignoring the alignment math and simply assumes a 1:1 mapping, for example. Most of the info is in the [PE COFF specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx), in the ReactOS sources, or [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6874/is-not-valid-win32-application-why/6878#6878)